# What mean dart_constant_default_value error on dart when setting default class default property value?

Tags: flutter, dart

Try Set write class on dart like this, but got an error dart(dart_constant_default_value). what happen and what the best way to set default value for DateTime property?

```
class NewConcern {
  NewConcern({
    required this.name,
    this.description = '',
    this.startDate = DateTime.now(),
    this.endDate = DateTime.now(),
    this.notify = false,
  });

  String name;
  String description;
  DateTime startDate;
  DateTime endDate;
  bool notify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is probably due to the missed @. use `@required`

Comment: No, current version of dart not use @ anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code add its work on my machine:

```
class NewConcern {
  NewConcern({
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.startDate,
    this.endDate,
    this.notify = false,
  });

  String name;
  String description;
  final DateTime startDate;
  final DateTime endDate;
  bool notify;
}
```

Comment: I need setup default value for startDate and endDate with DateTime now, so that property will not have possible to null.